# Swift generics. How to Specify output type?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

I have, for example, `enum` and what I want to archive is that each `enum case` can give me some different output type for, let's say a function.
Code example:

```
protocol MyType: Codable {
    var id: String {get set}
}

struct Type1: MyType {
    var id: String
    var name:String
}


struct Type2: MyType {
    var id: String
    var amount: Int
}


enum ReturnType {
    case first, second
    //Option 1
    func getElement() -> MyType {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return Type1(id: "1", name: "Name")
        case .second:
            return Type2(id: "2", amount: 10)
        }
    }

    //Some crap is here - don't pay attention
    func test<T:MyType>(data: T) -> T {
        return data
    }
}

//Option 2
func getElement(ofType type: ReturnType) -> MyType {
    switch type {
    case .first:
        return Type1(id: "1", name: "Name")
    case .second:
        return Type2(id: "2", amount: 10)
    }
}




let test1 = ReturnType.first.getElement() as! Type1
let test2 = ReturnType.second.getElement()
let test3 = getElement(ofType: .first)
```

So currently only `test1` is `Type1` but `test2` and `test3` is `MyType`
I want to archive strong typing without forcing that with `as!`

[image]

I was trying to do it with generics but didn't get any success.. 
Any thoughts?
Much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: All the compiler knows is that `getElement` returns an instance `MyType`.  If you want to treat the return value as a specific subclass of `MyType` then you need to downcast (either conditionally or forced).

Answer (score -1):

you can do the following:

```
enum ReturnType {
    case first, second
    //Option 1
    func getElement<T: MyType>() -> T {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return Type1(id: "1", name: "Name") as! T
        case .second:
            return Type2(id: "2", amount: 10) as! T
        }
    }

}

//Option 2
func getElement<T: MyType>(ofType type: ReturnType) -> T {
    switch type {
    case .first:
        return Type1(id: "1", name: "Name") as! T
    case .second:
        return Type2(id: "2", amount: 10) as! T
    }
}
```

after that when you call the func you just need to declare what type you want the variable as:

```
let test1: Type1 = ReturnType.first.getElement()
let test2: Type2 = ReturnType.second.getElement()
let test3: Type1 = getElement(ofType: .first)
```

hope it helped

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same thing?

Comment: nope because you are not force unwrapping, this is use case of generic func

Comment: the problem in your solution is that I can somewhere write:
   `let test1: Type2 = ReturnType.first.getElement()`

and the compiler will not argue but the app will crash